# Согласование подлежащее--сказуемое

Tags: согласование

> В темноте слышится шум и суета.
>   Правильно ли употребить глагол в единственном числе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Обе формы возможны (при выборе учитывается ряд факторов)**, но в приведенном примере в пользу ед. числа говорит  **препозиция сказуемого** (обратный порядок слов) и его пассивная форма:

В темноте **слышится** шум и суета. Вместе со светом **слышится** неразборчивый говор, смех. Но вот **слышится** шум, оживление.

**Но:** А мне **слышатся** грохот и крики. Неси меня туда, птица, откуда **слышатся** музыка и голоса. В этом многоголосом крике мне **слышатся** одновременно и восторг, и ужас.  (В этих примерах: а) одно из однородных подлежащих имеет форму мн. числа: б) однородные подлежащие рассматриваются отдельно и  сравниваются по времени).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Из Розенталя  [§ 190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1015483/236/Rozental_-_Spravochnik_po_pravopisaniyu,_proiznosheniyu,_literaturnomu_redaktirovaniyu.html)

**При прямом порядке слов** (сказуемое следует за однородными подлежащими) обычно употребляется форма **множественного числа** сказуемого, **при обратном порядке** (сказуемое предшествует подлежащим) — форма **единственного числа.**

Например:
а) Жара и засуха **стояли** более трех недель (Л. Толстой);
б) До Райского и Марфиньки **долетел** грубый говор, грубый смех, смешанные голоса, внезапно притихшие… (Гончаров);

Указанные положения **не носят категорического характера**, постпозитивное сказуемое может стоять в форме единственного, а препозитивное — в форме множественного числа (особенно часто в технической литературе).

Comment: _**Sibylla:** в пользу ед. числа говорит **препозиция** подлежащего_… === Гм… **Препозиция???**

Comment: Мне бы ссылочку.

Comment: Спасибо, ответ исправлен, ссылка на Розенталя приводится.